# Error coming from passport-local-mongoose, a node module when running my app.js file written in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var userIdSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    name: String,
    password: String,
    phonenumber: Number
});

userIdSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("NewUser", userIdSchema);']
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRPlQ.png)

Comment: Please check your last line of code, " '] "

Answer (score 0):

You have extra “(“ in the code

```
.then(({ user })...
```

Comment: It's typescript code
JS .then( function(){} ) but in TS .then( ()=>{} )